# How to automatic stock details (quantity increment)?

Tags: magento2, catalog, inventory, cataloginventory, multi-source-inventory

In the warehouse, if we scan the product it has to update in Magento inventory (i mean quantity has to increase).
How can I achieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

On scan give a call to your controller where you identify that its inventory quantity increment call.

Then load product by id or SKU and update its quantity by one.